# Android Dropbox Core Api upload file sample

Tags: android, upload, dropbox-api

Does anyone have a working Android Dropbox Core Api upload file sample to share?
Their examples are using Eclipse while the latest Android Studio is based on IntelliJ and I had very little success running them.
Please share a code snippet of the upload!
Thanks!

Comment: What issues did you run in to?

Comment: Got it working read bellow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question. I got this working; Read carefully the example on their website https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android;

- Make sure you have Dropbox app installed on your Android device and it points to the same account where your Dropbox App has been registered. You will need this app to Authenticate your app.
- Insure that in your AndoidManifest you have the following section

  ```
          <activity
                  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
              <intent-filter>
                  <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                  <data android:scheme="db-your key here" />
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
  ```
- make sure that in the above manifest your own API key is added with the **"db-"** prefix;
- don't forget to add the "onResume" section from their example. At that point you can save the "accessToken" to keep the app authenticated next time you start it.
- if you want the upload example to work replace the mDBApi.putFile... with

  ```
              if ( mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) 
              {
                  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                  try {                   
                      File file = new File("/somefile.txt");
                      FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                      DropboxAPI.Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/somefile.txt", inputStream, file.length(), null, null);
                      Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              });
              thread.start();}
  ```
- You can use better Async methods this is just a quick and dirty way to get it going. Trying to call the upload of the file in the main thread will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you added dropbox sdk into your gradle dependency.
- Check your Manifest file and add the following code in the application tag.

  ```
          <activity
                  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
              <intent-filter>
                  <!-- Change this to be db-followed by your app key-->
                  <data android:scheme="db-your key here" />
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
  ```
- don't forget to change the value of *data* tag.( **"db-"** + your app key).
- if you didn't create app from your dropbox account, you need to "create app" from dropbox website.
  (and then you can get app-key and access token).
- you can add the "accessToken" into "onResume" section from their [example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android). you can hardcode it to keep the app authenticated for next times.
- if you want the upload example just do the steps below :

  **1)** add a fab button into your activity.
  **2)** into the onClickListener() methode, call this methode :

  ```
  private void launchFilePicker() {
  // Launch intent to pick file for upload
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
  intent.setType("*/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);}
  ```

  **3)** override activityResult to get the data from file picker like this

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

          // This is the result of a call to launchFilePicker

          uploadFile(data.getData().toString());
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  **4)** implement upload methode like the code bellow

  ```
  private void uploadFile(String fileUri) {
  final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  dialog.setCancelable(false);
  dialog.setMessage("Uploading");
  dialog.show();

  new UploadFileTask(this, DropboxClientFactory.getClient(), new UploadFileTask.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onUploadComplete(FileMetadata result) {
          dialog.dismiss();

          String message = result.getName() + " size " + result.getSize() + " modified " +
                  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(result.getClientModified());
          Toast.makeText(FilesActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
          // Reload the folder
          loadData();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Exception e) {
          dialog.dismiss();

          Log.e(TAG, "Failed to upload file.", e);
          Toast.makeText(FilesActivity.this,
                  "An error has occurred",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
      }
    }).execute(fileUri, mPath);
  }
  ```

  **5)** create a java class name it to **UploadFileTask.java** and put the bellow code into it:

  ```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;

  import com.dropbox.core.DbxException;
  import com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxClientV2;
  import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.FileMetadata;
  import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.WriteMode;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;

  /**
   * Async task to upload a file to a directory
   */

  class UploadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FileMetadata> {

  private final Context mContext;
  private final DbxClientV2 mDbxClient;
  private final Callback mCallback;
  private Exception mException;

  public interface Callback {
    void onUploadComplete(FileMetadata result);
    void onError(Exception e);
  }

  UploadFileTask(Context context, DbxClientV2 dbxClient, Callback callback) {
    mContext = context;
    mDbxClient = dbxClient;
    mCallback = callback;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(FileMetadata result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (mException != null) {
      mCallback.onError(mException);
    } else if (result == null) {
      mCallback.onError(null);
    } else {
      mCallback.onUploadComplete(result);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected FileMetadata doInBackground(String... params) {
    String localUri = params[0];
    File localFile = UriHelpers.getFileForUri(mContext, Uri.parse(localUri));

    if (localFile != null) {
      String remoteFolderPath = params[1];

      // Note - this is not ensuring the name is a valid dropbox file name
      String remoteFileName = localFile.getName();

      try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile)) {
          return mDbxClient.files().uploadBuilder(remoteFolderPath + "/" + remoteFileName)
                  .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
                  .uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
      } catch (DbxException | IOException e) {
          mException = e;
      }
    }

    return null;
   }  
  }
  ```